# How to programmatically delete all values in custom CCK field for a given node?

Tags: entities

I'm on Drupal 6, and I have a multiple value CCK field. I need a PHP function to delete all the values in that field so I can later repopulate it. I am currently doing this:

```
if (isset($node->field_received_email[0]['value'])) {
  foreach($node->field_received_email as $key => $value) {
    $node->field_received_email[$key]['value'] = NULL;
  }
}
```

However, sometimes when I later repopulate it, I get Drupal dblog errors like:

> Duplicate entry '16026-133' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   query: INSERT INTO content_field_received_email (vid, nid, delta,
>   field_received_email_value) VALUES (16026, 15888, 133,
>   'whatever@email.com')

It appears that the primary key is remaining, and so when I go to write data again to the field it gives the duplicate primary key error.

Any suggestions on how to really delete all the values and keys from a multiple value CCK field in a given node so I can later re-write them?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to unset item

```
if (isset($node->field_received_email[0]['value'])) {
  foreach($node->field_received_email as $key => $value) {
    unset($node->field_received_email[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try. (Sorry I can't vote you up, this is my first post here.)

Comment: Seems to work! I imagine that also unsets the value associated with that key too, right?

Comment: yes, it's unset  array item and value too because value is a child for it

Comment: Great, it seems to be working just the way I wanted now. I really appreciate your help.